# Necessary to edit a question to show it's not a duplicate, or is a comment sufficient?

Tags: discussion, support

My [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14737/has-gps-been-used-beyond-geo) was marked as an "exact duplicate" of another question. I feel it is different in two important ways and I've left a comment to that effect.

But then I read the duplicate message more closely. It instructs the writer to *edit* the question:

> "*This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question. If this question is different, please edit it to explain how it is different or ask a new question.*"

Even if the question is not a duplicate after all, and if a mistake was made, the writer is asked to edit the question *as if there is still something wrong with it*. It's saying 'please fix your question to tell us why you don't think it needs fixing.'

Will my comment be seen and considered, or is it actually algorithmically necessary for me to edit the question to explain why I don't think it needs to be edited?

[image]

Comment: The reason you are asked to edit the question is for visibility of the distinction between the similar question and yours. If one person recalled that other question and marked it as a dupe, that is likely to happen again, when another member familiar with the collection looks at your question. People sometimes don't look at the comments, so it is better to put it in the question itself.

Comment: The reason actually stated is: "*This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question.*" I like your language better, though it's a bit too candid for a boilerplate as written. OK it's late here, I'll give it a go in the morning. Thanks @kimholder!

Comment: My pleasure. You've asked a lot of good questions lately. Cheers.